# Fragment android use error

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am trying to use a sample fragment to display a textview in my main activity but i face error when trying to intiate my fragment.

here is my my **fragment_main** xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_fragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="Fragment Main"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my **FragmentMain** class

```
package com.example.pfev2_4;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentMain extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
     ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, 
                               container, false);
        return view;
   }
}
```

this is my mainactivity xml that contains the fragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_PrenomUtilisateur_Main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_NomUtilisateur_Main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_ListeEvents_Main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Liste Evenements" />
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_ListeInvitations_Main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Liste Invitations" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_CreateEvent_Main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Créer nouvel événement" />

     <fragment 
         android:id="@+id/fragment1" 

         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         class="com.example.pfev2_4.FragmentMain"


        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" ></fragment>
         </LinearLayout>
```

and this is the main activity class

```
package controler;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.pfev2_4.R;
import model.*;
import com.example.pfev2_4.R.layout;
import com.example.pfev2_4.R.menu;

import android.R.integer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivitypfeV2_4 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


      public static ArrayList<Evenement> listeEvenementUtilisateur; 


    //composants  
     TextView txtView_NomUtilisateur,txtView_PrenomUtilisateur;
     Button btn_ListeEvenment,btn_CreerEvenement,btn_ListeInvitation,btn_PublierStatu;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activitypfe_v2_4);

        setTitle("DashBoard");

        listeEvenementUtilisateur=Authentification_Activity.services.ListeEvenmentUtilisateur(Authentification_Activity.user);
        //INITIALISATION DES COMPOSANTS
        txtView_NomUtilisateur=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_NomUtilisateur_Main);
        txtView_PrenomUtilisateur=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_PrenomUtilisateur_Main);
        btn_ListeEvenment=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_ListeEvents_Main);
        btn_CreerEvenement=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_CreateEvent_Main);
        btn_ListeInvitation=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_ListeInvitations_Main);

        //CONTROLER
        txtView_NomUtilisateur.setText(Authentification_Activity.user.getNomUtilisateur());
        txtView_PrenomUtilisateur.setText(Authentification_Activity.user.getPrenomUtilisateur());
        btn_ListeEvenment.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_CreerEvenement.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_ListeInvitation.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activitypfe_v2_4, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent newIntent;
        if(v == btn_ListeEvenment)
        {
            newIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShowListeEvents_Activity.class);
            startActivity(newIntent);
        }
        if(v==btn_CreerEvenement)
        {
            newIntent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CreateEvent_Activity.class);
            startActivity(newIntent);
        }
        if(v==btn_ListeInvitation)
        {
            newIntent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ListeInivtation_Activity.class);
            startActivity(newIntent);
        }


    }



}
```

when i lounch my application the log show these errors

```
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233): Process: com.example.pfev2_4, PID: 24233
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pfev2_4/controler.MainActivitypfeV2_4}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class fragment
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class fragment
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:359)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2010)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at controler.MainActivitypfeV2_4.onCreate(MainActivitypfeV2_4.java:35)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    ... 11 more
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.example.pfev2_4.FragmentMain that is not a Fragment
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4964)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    ... 21 more
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
04-16 03:12:26.753: E/AndroidRuntime(24233):    ... 25 more
```

Comment: in which device u test..?

Comment: `MainActivitypfeV2_4` should extend `FragmentActivity` since you are using the v4 support library